# How to switch to Login tab when form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a login page which has two forms sign up and login. Is has tabs to switch from login form to sign up form.

I want to know how can I show loin form when I am submitting the signup form on click of get started button.

I tried to put form action as #login but it did not work.

Login.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

<br>
<h1 align="center"> TASK 2017</h1>
<div class="form">

    <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">

        <div id="signup">
            <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

            <form action="Login.html" method="post">

                <div class="top-row">
                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            First Name<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>
                        Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>
                        Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get Started</button>

            </form>

        </div>

        <div id="login">
            <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

            <form action="/" method="post">

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>
                        Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>
                        Password<span class="req">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>

            <!--    <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>-->

                <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div><!-- tab-content -->

</div> <!-- /form -->
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {

  var $this = $(this),
      label = $this.prev('label');

      if (e.type === 'keyup') {
            if ($this.val() === '') {
          label.removeClass('active highlight');
        } else {
          label.addClass('active highlight');
        }
    } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
        if( $this.val() === '' ) {
            label.removeClass('active highlight'); 
            } else {
            label.removeClass('highlight');   
            }   
    } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

      if( $this.val() === '' ) {
            label.removeClass('highlight'); 
            } 
      else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
            label.addClass('highlight');
            }
    }

});

$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

  target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();

  $(target).fadeIn(600);

});
```

How to do this? Please help.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the active tab when the page is loaded to the tab present in the url:

```
$(document).ready( (function () {
   target = $(this);
  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();

  $(target).fadeIn(600);

}).bind("#"+(window.location.href.split("#")[1]||"signup")));
```

Then you can go to http://example.com/login.html#login

Comment: I tried your code but on submitting the form I can see only sign up and login buttons not the login form.@Jonas w

Comment: @Sid ive edited just a few minutes ago, did you tried theup to date code?

Comment: yes the updated code. on page load I can only see buttons on both the form now.

Comment: still its working same, for sign up form I have put action as Login.html its fine right?

Comment: @Sid no login.html#login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143738/discussion-between-sid-and-jonas-w).